# Max Planck - what's the $B$?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

Planck says

> $$B_\nu(T)=\frac{2\nu^2}{c^2}\,\frac{h\nu}{\mathrm{e}^{h\nu/k_BT}-1}.$$

It is power emitted per unit area per unit angle per unit frequency. This is what I'm curious now.

Let's say we got a black body at T = 300K. I want to calculate power emitted when wavelength is 500nm. So I plugin in 300K and instead of , we put c/λ = c/500.

Let's say the end result I got was 700. Don't focus on numbers. I'm trying to understand what 700 is.

Question 1:

- Is it the power emitted at 500nm as I wanted
- do I need to multiply 700 by the area of object and if so, why? The whole area just doesn't emit this 500nm wavelength.

Question 2:

Mainly, I think 700 is the power emitted by object at 1cm^3 at 500nm.  what does per unit frequency mean in this context then ?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Q1: Is the below already an integral derived from what you said ? and I guess, angle got integrated into `π`.

Q2: so, I think the above formula(2nd one in the picture) states what you said in the comments. In the wikipedias's formula, if I put `10mm` in the formula as a wavelength, I would get energy emitted per 1cm^3 in the range of 10mm and 11mm wavelengths, but with the formula shown in the picture, I can even go in a shorter range, for example if I want to know the enery in the range of 10mm and 10.001mm, then I would put 10 for `Λ` and `0.001` for `dλ`.   The same can't be achieved with wikipedia's general formula as it only gives you the energy per unit wavelength which is 1mm in the SI system. Is this all correct ?

Comment: The downvotes aren't justified. This question contains several common mistakes made by noobs: e.g.: calling solid angle, "angle", swapping $\nu$ and $\lambda$ w/o a Jacobian, not knowing what a PDF is and why the power radiated at 500 nm is zero, confusing volume/surface are and not doing a dimensional check, number w/o units.... basically everything about it is a misconception, which is what makes it a good question.

Comment: I agree with @JEB about the downvotes. We had a question the other day where the OP was missing a factor of pi exactly because of this non-triviality in the definition of these properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mainly, I think 700 is the power emitted by object at 1cm^3 at 500nm. what does per unit frequency mean in this context then ?

If this were the case, then the object would be emitting approximately $700$ W of power for every wavelength between, say $500$ nm and $501$ nm. How many wavelengths are in that interval, and what would that mean about the total power being emitted by the body?

---

$B_\nu(T)$ is defined by the fact that the total power being emitted per unit surface area between frequencies $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ is given by
$$P=\int \mathrm d\Omega \int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2}\mathrm d\nu\  B_\nu(T)\cos(\theta) $$
where the angular integral is performed over the hemisphere above the point in question. Integration over the angular variables yields a factor of $\pi$, and so this becomes

$$P = \pi \int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2} \mathrm d\nu \ B_\nu(T)$$
Assuming that $\nu_2-\nu_1 \equiv \delta \nu$ is sufficiently small$^\dagger$, this is approximately equal to $\pi B_\nu(T) \delta \nu$. Therefore, $\pi B_\nu(T)$ is (approximately) the power emitted per square meter of surface area by the body at frequencies in the range $[\nu-\delta\nu/2,\nu+\delta\nu/2]$, **divided by $\delta\nu$**. That is the meaning of "per unit frequency."

$^\dagger$As usual, "sufficiently small" means that the function does not change much over the range $[\nu_1,\nu_2]$. To be more precise, this would mean that
$$\frac{\delta \nu}{B_\nu(T)}\frac{d B_\nu(t)}{d\nu} \ll 1$$

Comment: If this were the case, then the object would be emitting approximately 700
 W of power for every wavelength between, say 500 nm and 501 nm.” - i dont get this. The reason I supplied 500nm in the equation is because I wanted to know the energy at this specific frequency.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze I was trying to lead you to the realization that if $B_\nu(T)$ gave you the power being emitted at a specific frequency, then it would have to be radiating an infinite amount of power because $B_\nu$ would be approximately the same for $\nu=500$ nm, $500.0001$ nm, $500.0000001$ nm, ...

Comment: so can we say that per unit frequency means 1hz ? Meaning that if I calculate the power for 10hz and get 300, then this is the power emitted in the range of 10-11hz. Similarly, if i calculate it for 50hz and get 400 power, it is the power emitted in the range of 50-51. Is this true ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze If you calculate $\pi B_\nu(T)$ for $\nu=10$ Hz and get $300$, then that is (approximately) the power emitted **per unit surface area** in the range $10-11$ Hz. If you want it to be *exactly* true, you'd need to integrate $\pi B_\nu(T)$ between $\nu=10$ and $11$ Hz.

Comment: Would I need to multiply the result with the surface area ?  But why ? The whole area just doesn't emit this 500nm wavelength. it is part of some area that emits this. Other parts of area emits different wavelength.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze *Every* part of the surface emits at *every* wavelength. Assuming that every part of the surface is at the same temperature, then this function is the same everywhere and you can find the total power being radiated in the range $10-11$ Hz by multiplying $\pi B_\nu(T)$ by the total surface area. If different parts of the surface are at different temperatures, then you'd have to write $T$ as a function of position on the surface and then perform another integral.

Comment: Every part of the surface emits every wavelength. - this is interesting. I thought in the objects, due to electrons moving in some parts of the object faster and in another parts of the objects slower, thats what would cause different wavelengths. Does this mean even in a very small area(very very small at T), it would emit all wavelengths because even in small area, some electrons are faster and some not ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze It's not necessarily about the speed with which electrons are moving. Remember that an ideal black body is not composed of atoms or molecules or electrons or anything else - it is an imaginary construct which is defined by the fact that it absorbs 100% of all EM radiation incident upon it. Real objects (stars, planets, rocks, people) are not black bodies, but can under certain circumstances be *approximated* as black bodies. The actual mechanisms for how that radiation is absorbed and re-emitted vary depending on the system.

Comment: Then why do we use planck formula for a star ? If star is not black body, formula is wrong. Or we say that star is very close to black body and hence even though formula is wrong, its results are still very close to the correct results. ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze Because you bring up electrons, the surface of a star is well-approximated as a black body because the free electrons and ions constitute a plasma which readily absorbs and emits radiation via Compton scattering and bremsstrahlung (and their inverse processes). Even 1 $mm^{3}$ of the photosphere has on the order of $10^{14}$ electrons and protons scattering constantly off of photons and each other. For that reason, it is well-approximated as a black body, as any incident radiation is absorbed extremely quickly.

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze More generally, **no** real systems are *ever* perfectly described by any model we can reasonably write down. The sun isn't a black body, electrons aren't point particles, boxes moving across the floor are neither points nor rigid extended objects. We come up with idealized models and then adapt them as best as we can to describe real things, but it's never perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145474/discussion-between-giorgi-lagidze-and-j-murray).

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I understood it mostly. I only got 2 questions left to confirm my knowledge. I updated my question. There's a word EDIT in the question.. I'd appreciate so much if you could let me know your thoughts about these 2.